# how to make date picker in the form of input filed in react native

Tags: react-native

i was able to open  date picker with button  i am trying to open it with text input

here is i how i open my calender

`<Button onPress={displayDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />`

i am looking for something like this that will open the calender when clicked on textinput fild

```
  <TextInput
          style={styles.forminput}
          label=" Date of Birth"
          value=""
          onclick={displayDatepicker}
        />
```

Comment: https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/react-native-date-picker-with-input-example
reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this maybe it will work.

```
 <TextInput
      style={styles.forminput}
      label=" Date of Birth"
      value=""
      onPressIn={displayDatepicker}
    />
```

or this will also work,

```
   <TextInput
      style={styles.forminput}
      label=" Date of Birth"
      value=""
      onFocus={displayDatepicker}
    />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your code like this,

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    activeOpcaity={1}
    onPress={() => setShowCalender(true)}>
<TextInput  value={calenderDate} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```